# C# calling wrong method at runtime

Tags: c#, abstraction, callstack

Very strange one here. I'm not really sure how far I need to go to produce a minimal code example.

I have the following code:

```
public class TruckService : ViperService<Truck, TruckViewModel>, ITruckService
{
    public override async Task<Truck> Insert(Truck entity)
    {
        var viperInsert = await base.Insert(entity);
        //Then does other logic
    }
}
```

But when executing this code it calls the Update method on the base class instead?

```
public abstract class ViperService<T, TVM> : IViperService<T, TVM> where T : ViperEntity where TVM : ViperViewModel
{
    public virtual Task<T> Insert(T entity)
    {
        return this.viperRepository.Insert(entity);
    }

    public virtual Task<T> Update(T entity)
    {
        return this.viperRepository.Update(entity);
    }
}
```

Here is the call stack:
[image: Call Stack]

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Comment: are you sure that in your `//Then does other logic` there is not Update call? in line 82 or 57 (not sure in call stack ;) )

Comment: "//Then does other logic" - any chance you're in there?

Comment: LIne 57 is the base.Insert call

Comment: I have managed to sort it, I just restarted visual studio in the end. However still a bizarre occurrence that I have never seen in 10 years of programming